# How to Forward /var/log/yum.log to Remote Logging Server using rsyslog.conf?

Tags: linux, installation, logging, yum, syslog

Gents,
I am trying to find a way to forward `/var/log/yum.log` towards Remote Logging Server using `rsyslog.conf` in my RHEL7. But Not happening.

I have tried this approach but no luck -

> $InputFileName /var/log/yum.log $InputFileSeverity info
> $InputFileFacility local2 $InputRunFileMonitor

Also, I have tried using `*.*` in `rsyslog.conf` but no luck. Even my `/var/log/messages` do not receive any Installation logs (I don't know why).

Please advise.

Comment: Compare to your  rsyslog.conf to the answer here? https://serverfault.com/a/396194/411612 . Make sure you have `$ModLoad imfile` in particular to use `$InputFile` configs

Comment: Tried this way. But no luck. I dont know why dont I see YUM logs in /var/log/messages.

`$ModLoad imfile
$InputFileName /var/log/yum.log
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local3
$InputRunFileMonitor`